# What is the highest O Power Level in Pokemon X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

So I have seen some questions related to how fast O-Powers level up but I am curious as to how high they can go. I have a level 2 O-Power, can it get to level 3? And once it does, can I take it higher than that?

Comment: I just unlocked a level 3 O-Power, so yes, it can go to level 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maximum is level 3, source [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/xy/opowers.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

you can get lv S but its from hacking soon to be a Special Distribution

Comment: Source? I can confirm it exists, someone used it on me recently. I was wondering how to get it...